# Syntax error when using asp.net Repeater in Javascript

Tags: asp.net, json, repeater

I want to use asp.net repeater to get data in a variable in JSON type. I am using Repeater in Javascript. But its giving me syntax error. Here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var markers = [enter code here
<asp:Repeater runat='server'></asp:Repeater>

        <asp:Repeater ID="rptMarkers" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
                 {
                     "title": '<%# Eval("Name") %>',
                 "lat": '<%# Eval("Latitude") %>',
                 "lng": '<%# Eval("Longitude") %>',
                 "description": '<%# Eval("Description") %>'
             }
    </ItemTemplate>
    <SeparatorTemplate>
        ,
    </SeparatorTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
    ];
    </script>
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: add the syntax error message (or am I missing it in question text somewhere?)

Comment: The code is underlined red showing that there is some problem. When i hover over the code it says syntax Error. I am using VS 2012.

Comment: Any compiler I saw (MSVC++ included) has error log usually on the bottom of the source code page where all warnings and errors are. Compilation usually stops on 1st error set focus on the line with error and highlight the error code in that log. (there you read the syntax error message and more info like ';' expected or some numeric value which tells what is wrong. copy that whole text line here. if there is none then that can be some bug in your IDE (like invalid translation,unknown error or just turned off error log).

Answer (score 1):

It's an old post but this reference helped me figure out the exact same issue.
[asp repeater syntax error](http://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/28357198/asp-repeater-issue-not-working-or-missing.html)

The idea is to use code-behind to generate your repeater list.

```
  var markers = [
// start of generated objects from code-behind

        <%=getMarkerObjects() %>

// end of generated objects from code-behind
    ];
```

Now in your code-behind

```
    Protected Function getMarkerObjects() As String
    Const indent As String = "    "
    Dim dt = New DataTable
    dt.Columns.AddRange({New DataColumn("Name", GetType(String)), New DataColumn("Latitude", GetType(Double)), New DataColumn("Longitude", GetType(Double)), New DataColumn("Description", GetType(String))})
    dt.Rows.Add({"p1", 32.2217, -110.9264, "p1"})
    dt.Rows.Add({"p2", 31.9556, -110.3067, "p2"})
    Dim ret As String = String.Empty
    For Each r In dt.Rows
        ret &= IIf(ret.Equals(String.Empty), "", indent & "," & vbCrLf) &
            indent & "{" & vbCrLf &
                indent & indent & """title"": '" & r("Name") & "'," & vbCrLf &
                indent & indent & """lat"": '" & r("Latitude") & "'," & vbCrLf &
                indent & indent & """lng"": '" & r("Longitude") & "'," & vbCrLf &
                indent & indent & """description"": '" & r("Description") & "'" & vbCrLf &
            indent & "}" & vbCrLf
    Next
    Return ret
End Function
```

Comment: @Drew Just did, prematurely posted